# Memory leak - Android activities held by android.os.Message

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I'm working on an application where 90% of the activities inherit from a common activity and all these activities leak, meaning that if I go from `A->B` and then `B->A` (`finish()` is called), `B`'s `onDestroy()` gets called but it still leaks (checked with MAT).

The leaked activities are quite big (10MB~) so after going back and forth a few times the app crashes with OOM.

I've checked the heap dump and followed the path to GC roots for the leaking activities and they all look like this:
[image]

So I guess it's something in the common superclass that's leaking. I've already checked that all the BroadcastReceivers and listeners are unregistered when the activities get destroyed and there are no `Handler`s used nor anonymous inner classes which may be causing the leak (it seems to me, at least).

What could be the cause of the leak? Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've found that there are two pieces of code that when commented out the activities are not leaking anymore:

1. Some lines of code that instantiate a `ProgressDialog`.
2. A call to `postDelayed` with an anonymous `Runnable`.

In the first case, the dialog's `dismiss()` function is called before destruction, so I don't know why this could be the problem. In the second case, removeCallbacks is called for the `Runnable` in `onPause`, so theoretically it's properly cleaned, isnt' it?

Cheers.

Comment: My first's shot would be an anonymous or inner class that is keeping a reference to activity's context. Post your activity's code so we can take a look on it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't disclose the code and it's quite huge and messy. Does the MAT screenshot tell you anything?

Comment: It tells me that you're leaking the context and it's being held by a message queue. First, verify if there is any non-static inner class in your activity. Objects from non-static inner classes hold a reference to its parent, so you may want double-check it. Also double-check the runnable which you're posting: does it take too long to run? As long as it is in the message queue, the activity's context will not be destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turn out to be the anonymous `Runnable` in `postDelayed`. This `Runnable` was called with the `postDelayed()` function of the content view of the base activity, so it was something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ...
    mCallback = new Runnable() { ... };
    getContentView().postDelayed(mCallback, mDelay);
}
```

The surprising part was that this callback was removed in `onPause()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    ...
    getContentView().removeCallbacks(mCallback);
    mCallback = null;
}
```

Why this didn't prevent the leak is still a mistery to me. At first I tried using `getContentView().getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` and it fixed the leak, but then the app had things completely broken apart in seemingly unrelated places.

In the end what fixed the leak was creating a `Handler` instance and calling `postDelayed()` and `removeCallbacks()` on this handler.

Comment: Hey thats really a mistery. It would have been interesting to log the boolean values returned by `getContentView.postDelayed` and `getContentView.removeCallbacks`.Looks like a really bad API design to me to expose such methods in View. I'd have left those two methods in the Handler class only. And also makes me thing the Handler implementation could be much more robust, in case it's a different one.

Comment: I did check the return value of `removeCallbacks` and it was always returning true, nothing seemed apparently wrong to me. I agree the API design is a bit dodgy, not sure why those functions are there for...